# neo4j.ClientError: [Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized]

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j  i tried to insert a data into neo4j database via node4js but error has occurred any resolve this problem.

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var neo4j=require('neo4j');
var neo4jDB = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:7474/browser');
var crypto=require('crypto');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
var appSecret=process.env.APP_SECRET;
app.get('/',function (req,res){
    res.send("Hello World");
})

app.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('test.html',{'root': __dirname });
})

app.post('/insert',function (req,res){
     var email = req.body['email'];
     var password = req.body['password'];
          var query = [
             'CREATE (user:User {newUser})',
                 'RETURN user'
            ].join('\n');
     var params = {
         newUser: {
           email: email,
           password: password,
         }
     };                         
     neo4jDB.cypher({
       query: query,
          params: params
       }, 
       function(err,user){
         if(err) throw err;
         console.log(user);
         res.send("Record has been inserted")
     });
})
app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: error stack trace ?

Comment: neo4j.ClientError: [Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized] its my error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Neo4j server requires an authentication (the default setting), so you have to provide a username and a password to connect to it.

According to the [documentation for the "neo4j" npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j#usage), this is done in the URL of the Neo4j server:

```
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://username:password@localhost:7474');
```